# Mocha/Chai testing middleware header

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have been trying to learn Mocha/Chai unit testing libraries, and have been following NodeJS course by Maximillian on Udemy.

Got stuck on testing middleware based on this course.

My question is what is the proper way to use Mocha/Chai for unit testing middleware errors?

You can see my code below.

Auth Middleware:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const HttpError = require("../models/http-error");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
    return next();
  }
  try {

    const authHeader = req.get('Authorization');
    if(!authHeader){
      return next(new HttpError('Not authenticated', 401));
    }

    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]; // Authorization: 'Bearer TOKEN'
    if (!token) {
      return next(new HttpError("Authentication failed!", 401));
    }

    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, "supersecret_dont_share");
    req.userData = { userId: decodedToken.userId };
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new HttpError("Authentication failed!", 401));
  }
};
```

HttpError:

```
class HttpError extends Error{
    constructor(message, errorCode){
        super(message);
        this.code = errorCode;
    }
}

module.exports = HttpError;
```

authMiddleware.test.js:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const HttpError = require("../models/http-error");

const authMiddleware = require('../middleware/check-auth');

it('It should throw an error if no auth header is present', function(){
    const req = {
        get: function () {
            return null;
        }
    }

    const httpError = new HttpError('Not authenticated', 401);

    expect(authMiddleware.bind(this, req, {}, ()=>{})).to.have.property('message');
});
```

Tried with:

```
expect(authMiddleware.bind(this, req, {}, ()=>{})).to.throw();
expect(authMiddleware.bind(this, req, {}, ()=>{})).to.throw(Error);
expect(authMiddleware.bind(this, req, {}, ()=>{})).to.throw(HttpError);
expect(authMiddleware.bind(this, req, {}, ()=>{})).to.be.instanceOf(HttpError);
expect(authMiddleware.bind(this, req, {}, ()=>{})).to.be.instanceOf(Error);
expect(authMiddleware.bind(this, req, {}, ()=>{})).to.have.property('message');
```

All above fail the test.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as you and I solved it like this:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const { expect } = chai;

const sinon = require("sinon");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const authMiddleware = require("../middleware/check-auth");
const HttpError = require("../models/http-error");

describe("authenticate middleware", () => {
  let req, res, next;

  beforeEach(() => {
    req = {
      headers: {},
      cookies: {},
    };
    res = {
      removeHeader: sinon.spy(),
    };
    next = sinon.spy();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it("should throw an error if no authorization header or cookie is present", async () => {
    await authMiddleware(req, res, next);

    expect(next.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(next.calledWith(sinon.match.instanceOf(HttpError))).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Remember to add:

```
 npm install --save-dev chai-as-promised
```